# How to fix connection was reset error in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, http

I use Laravel 6.2. I try to upload a video. The size is ~700mb, but when I submit the form I receive the following error in Chrome:

> `The connection was reset`

I tried to upload a video which has ~5mb size and it worked fine.

I disabled XCache, but it did not work.

P.s: Post_max_size and upload file size is 2gb

Comment: Can you provide further information on how you are performing the upload, you will need to cater for a longer execution time on both the server and client and will most likely want to chunk your upload. Check out some upload libraries such as [filepond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/).

Comment: Possibly a timeout issue - you my have a fast download speed but a shockingly slow upload - take your 5mb upload time, multiply by 140 (700 / 5) and see if that looks like it might be an issue for the server you are uploading to.

Comment: Unflux, it is a simple input inside a form. I select a video, then submit it. I will check filepond, thank you.

Comment: Don, my upload speed is 100mb, I do not think it is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

**Apache:** Edit your `httpd.conf` file, and increase `max_execution_time` as well as `max_input_time`:

```
<Directory "[path/to/this/directory]"> 
    php_value upload_max_filesize 2000M 
    php_value post_max_size 2000M 
    php_value max_execution_time 600 
    php_value max_input_time 600 
</Directory>
```

**PHP**: you can also increase time and size in your `php.ini` file:

```
post_max_size = 2G
memory_limit = 512M
max_execution_time = 36000
max_input_time = 60
```

Then, restart your Apache server and try again.